# Can't generate documentation using swagger on laravel

Tags: laravel, api, swagger

i recently use swagger in my project, i'm using L5-swagger from DarkaOnLine. I was followed installation step. After i installed it, i add this code at my controller

```
/**
* @SWG\Swagger(
*   basePath="/users",
*   @SWG\Info(
*     title="List all available users",
*     version="1.0.0"
*   )
* )
*/
```

After that, i run "php artisan l5-swagger:generate" in terminal. But i got this error :

"Required @OAS\Info() not found"

Comment: Which version of swagger-php are you using?

Comment: i am using version 5.5

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to replace the version of swagger-php to 2.0. The same error is mention in SwaggerLume of DarkaOnLine on Github.

See here: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume/issues/51

Comment: can you tell me how to change it?

Comment: Here is the documentation and official GitHub link, please see https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php

Answer (score 0):

You will need

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
*/
```

but after this line of code, you will have a new error. So put the info below the starting brackets of class, and above the controller you need, but the second block of code, of course you need to modify it for your routes.

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/projects",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="Display a listing of projects.")
 * )
 */
```